# regex match patern before and after a underscore

Tags: java, php, javascript, regex, kaltura

I have a file name convention {referenceId}_{flavor name}.mp4 in kaltura.
or if you are familiar with kaltura then tell me the slugRegex i could use for this naming convention that would support pre-encoded file ingestion

I have to extract referenceId and filename from it.

I'm using

```
/(?P)_(?P)[.]\w{3,}/
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var filename = "referenceId_flavor-name.mp4";
var parts = filename.match(/([^_]+)_([^.]+)\.(\w{3})/i);
// parts is an array with 4 elements
// ["referenceId_flavor-name.mp4", "referenceId", "flavor-name", "mp4];
```

Comment: actually i have a file name abc_1000.mp4 in tis abc is reference Id and 1000 is flavor name.i'm using (?P<referenceId>)_(?P<flavorName>)[.]\w{3,}/  . referenceId is group name so flavorName is .

Answer (score 0):

```
var file = 'refID_name.mp4',
    parts = file.match(/^([^_]+)_(.+)\.mp4/, file);
```

Returns array:

```
[
    'refID_name.mp4', //the whole match is always match 0
    'refID', //sub-match 1
    'name' //sub-match 2
]
```

Comment: I solved the issue by removing regex expression. kaltura take it as default

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Parse file name according to defined slugRegex and set the extracted parsedSlug and parsedFlavor.
 * The following expressions are currently recognized and used:
 *  - (?P<referenceId>\w+) - will be used as the drop folder file's parsed slug.
 *  - (?P<flavorName>\w+)  - will be used as the drop folder file's parsed flavor. 
 *  - (?P<userId>\[\w\@\.]+) - will be used as the drop folder file entry's parsed user id.
 * @return bool true if file name matches the slugRegex or false otherwise
 */
private function parseRegex(DropFolderContentFileHandlerConfig $fileHandlerConfig, $fileName, &$parsedSlug, &$parsedFlavor, &$parsedUserId)
{
    $matches = null;
    $slugRegex = $fileHandlerConfig->getSlugRegex();
    if(is_null($slugRegex) || empty($slugRegex))
    {
        $slugRegex = self::DEFAULT_SLUG_REGEX;
    }
    $matchFound = preg_match($slugRegex, $fileName, $matches);
    KalturaLog::debug('slug regex: ' . $slugRegex . ' file name:' . $fileName);
    if ($matchFound) 
    {
        $parsedSlug   = isset($matches[self::REFERENCE_ID_WILDCARD]) ? $matches[self::REFERENCE_ID_WILDCARD] : null;
        $parsedFlavor = isset($matches[self::FLAVOR_NAME_WILDCARD])  ? $matches[self::FLAVOR_NAME_WILDCARD]  : null;
        $parsedUserId = isset($matches[self::USER_ID_WILDCARD])  ? $matches[self::USER_ID_WILDCARD]  : null;
        KalturaLog::debug('Parsed slug ['.$parsedSlug.'], Parsed flavor ['.$parsedFlavor.'], parsed user id ['. $parsedUserId .']');
    }
    if(!$parsedSlug)
        $matchFound = false;
    return $matchFound;
}
```

is the code that deals with the regex. I used `/(?P<referenceId>.+)_(?P<flavorName>.+)[.]\w{3,}/` and following this tutorial [enter link description here](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Drop-Folder-Configuration-in-Kaltura)